# SQL: Compare 2 tables and state if data was found

Tags: sql, datetime, mariadb, subquery, left-join

I'm a novice when it comes to SQL, so forgive me if this is a dumb question.

I have 2 tables, one with a list of users, and one that holds email history data.

Users Table:

```
userID fName  lName ...
1      John   Smith
2      Jane   Doe
3      Kevin  Cooper
```

Email History Table:

```
emailID userID subject sendDate ...
1       6      welcome 2020-10-17
2       3      hello   2020-10-20
3       7      welcome 2020-10-23
```

I am wanting to do some sort of select statement that would compare every customer in table 1, to every email in table 2 based on some sort of search query (in this case where subject = "hello" and sendDate = "2020-10-20" and would return something like this:

Returned Query:

```
userID  fName  lName  ...  emailSent?
1       John   Smith  ...  No
2       Jane   Doe    ...  No
3       Kevin  Cooper ...  Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

One option uses `exists` and a correlated subquery:

```
select u.*, 
    exists (
        select 1
        from emailhistory eh
        where eh.userid = u.userid and eh.subject = 'hello' and eh.senddate = '2020-20-20'
    ) emailSent
from users u
```

This gives you `0`/`1` values in column `emailSent`, where `1` indicates that a match exists. As compared to the `left join` approach, the upside is that it does not "multiplies" the user rows if more than one match is found in the history table.

For performance, consider an index on `emailhistory(userid, subject, senddate)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can left join the email table on, putting your date and subject criteria in the where clause:

```
SELECT
  u.userid,
  u.fname,
  u.lname,
  case when eh.emailid is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end as emailsent
FROM
  users u
  LEFT JOIN 
  emailhistory eh 
  ON 
    u.userid = eh.emailid AND
    eh.subject = 'hello' AND
    eh.senddate = '2020-10-20'
```

This conceptually filters the email table down to just that subject and day, then joins those records onto the users table. You get every row from users and only rows from emailhistory that match on userid, and also had that subject/date. You can then examine whether the emailid (a key of the join) is null or not; the only way it can be null is if no email was sent to that user on that date with that subject